# System.InvalidCastException was unhandled Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have received the error as stated in my title and being a new user to vb.net trying to make sense of it. I would be grateful if someone could explain the correct way to troubleshoot this error as I am not experienced enough to know where to start with this type of error.

If it helps, this is what I am trying to do. I have a contextmenu in a listbox that when I right click on an entry, displays the value of the member in that cell. The messagebox appears with the correct value, but when I click to close the box, this error appears. Many thanks

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs'.
```

This is the code I think I should show.

```
Private Sub HideToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles pnlContextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked, HideToolStripMenuItem.Click
        'Get the text of the item that was clicked on.
        Try
            MessageBox.Show(txtCustomerActive.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Opening_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles pnlContextMenuStrip1.Opening

    End Sub
```

**UPDATE:** I enabled Stirct On in my project and after making some minor changes to the code I am left with this which I think refers to the error.

```
Error   1   Method 'Private Sub HideToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs)' cannot handle event 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature.  C:\Users\domain\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Login\btLogin\vb\Form2.vb 153 175 Login
```

Comment: You should show us the code that causes this exception.

Comment: @Tim thats the problem I am not sure which code I should post for inspection. Would it be the listbox or the datagridview or the contextmenu. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ToolStripItem.Click`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has this parameters:

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

[`ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemclickedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherits from [`System.EventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so it's implicitely of type `EventArgs`. A child has all abilities of it's parent but not vice-versa.

I assume you simply have to change that signature to:

```
Private Sub HideToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles pnlContextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked, HideToolStripMenuItem.Click
```

So just change `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs` to `EventArgs`.

Comment: This now produces this error: Error 1 'Private Sub HideToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. C:\Users\domain\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\btLogin\btLogin\vb\Form2.vb 155 17 Login

Comment: @user1532468: Then you have another `HideToolStripMenuItem_Click`. Remove one.